# Unable to execute any multisig transaction on Polkadot

Tags: polkadot, multisig, identity

I started off wanting to set and identity for a multisig I created on Polkadot, but cannot execute any transactions from the multisig.

[image: Accounts]

I have an account, currently with ~6 DOT and a newly created multisig, funded with 60 DOT.  Attempting to set the identity from the multisig fails, as does any attempt to create a transaction, or transfer funds (even 1 DOT fails).

[image]

Checking the TX hash revels that it fails due to `Failed （SignatoriesOutOfOrder）` (The multisig was just created, so I fail to see how the signatories are out of order.

```
[
  {
    name: "threshold",
    type: "U16",
    type_name: "u16",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "other_signatories",
    type: "Vec<[U8; 32]>",
    type_name: "Vec<AccountId>",
    value: [
      "0xbe5039c1ea1010712c27c0c771960de253a540e859124213d9e12d9444fdc93b",
      "0x18930b3ba985e076d3b466e08e1caf1a1b1358733c7ec74c7cea066e5a16ff64"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "maybe_timepoint",
    type: "option<pallet_multisig:Timepoint>",
    type_name: "Option<Timepoint<BlockNumber>>",
    value: null
  },
  {
    name: "call",
    type: "Call",
    type_name: "Box<<T as Config>::RuntimeCall>",
    value: {
      call_index: "1c01",
      call_module: "Identity",
      call_name: "set_identity",
      params: [
        {
          name: "info",
          type: "pallet_identity:types:IdentityInfo",
          value: {
            additional: null,
            display: {
              Raw13: "Exiled Racers"
            },
            email: {
              Raw21: "info@exiledracers.com"
            },
            image: {
              None: "NULL"
            },
            legal: {
              None: "NULL"
            },
            pgp_fingerprint: null,
            riot: {
              None: "NULL"
            },
            twitter: {
              Raw13: "@exiledracers"
            },
            web: {
              Raw24: "https://exiledracers.com"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    name: "max_weight",
    type: "sp_weights:weight_v2:Weight",
    type_name: "Weight",
    value: {
      proof_size: 0,
      ref_time: 0
    }
  }
]
```

Or it fails with `Failed （InsufficientBalance）` (attempting to transfer 1 DOT).

[image]

I have no idea why this is failing, or how to debug it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One question I have is if you are executing the multisig transaction from polkadot-js apps or from your own script/code ?

Without knowing the answer to the above question, here are some thoughts/concerns based on the info you shared :

- Regarding the `Failed（SignatoriesOutOfOrder）` error as Bill mentioned, you need to exclude the sender and sort the signatories. This is also shown in the [multisig example in txwrapper-core](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/62faea5bb276b9a8aa4e9155b24c29b5d4d46392/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig/src/multisig.ts) :

  - When we call [approveAsMulti](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/62faea5bb276b9a8aa4e9155b24c29b5d4d46392/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig/src/multisig.ts#L333) and the sender is Alice, we need to exclude Alice from the signatories and sort the array (we do that in this [function](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/62faea5bb276b9a8aa4e9155b24c29b5d4d46392/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig/src/multisig.ts#L105L120)). So then the array that we pass as an argument is the [otherSignatoriesSortedExAlice](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/62faea5bb276b9a8aa4e9155b24c29b5d4d46392/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig/src/multisig.ts#L336).
  - Then when we call the [asMulti](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/62faea5bb276b9a8aa4e9155b24c29b5d4d46392/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig/src/multisig.ts#L498) and the sender is Bob, we need to  exclude Bob from the signatories and sort the array. So then what we pass as an argument is the [otherSignatoriesSortedExBob](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/62faea5bb276b9a8aa4e9155b24c29b5d4d46392/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig/src/multisig.ts#L501).
- The `Failed InsufficientBalance）` error that you get is interesting but maybe it is related to the fact that from the signatories that you shared :

  - the account [13ijWGM4g7oyk4H8bKz15cZM4MNuPxV5FLzoJ9fzUfUwRKWV](https://polkadot.subscan.io/account/13ijWGM4g7oyk4H8bKz15cZM4MNuPxV5FLzoJ9fzUfUwRKWV) has sufficient balance
  - same for the account [15JXvwngPdVPdxDxK6Bo68cf5JV6Z7s9tzYty7qVffKggrSb](https://polkadot.subscan.io/account/15JXvwngPdVPdxDxK6Bo68cf5JV6Z7s9tzYty7qVffKggrSb?tab=extrinsic)
  - but then I could not find the 3rd signatory [1ZDqARs7FJxnj2ntDRH2ouo3UEYGJpqUCd2zcnNc8wP5ciF](https://polkadot.subscan.io/account/1ZDqARs7FJxnj2ntDRH2ouo3UEYGJpqUCd2zcnNc8wP5ciF)

  Maybe this is related?
- Regarding the failed `asMulti` calls ([16952833-2](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/16952833-2) and [16952356-2](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/16952356-2)) just to mention that :

  - It is recommended to use [asMulti](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e526f80a91f75a3811059d4ee19b0f190005c5a2/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L401) when it is the final approval (so there is one or more successful `approveAsMulti` that have preceded it -depending on the threshold you set-) and
  - Use [approveAsMulti](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e526f80a91f75a3811059d4ee19b0f190005c5a2/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L335L336) for the rest of the approvals.

Last, in the [README](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/tree/62faea5bb276b9a8aa4e9155b24c29b5d4d46392/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig#key-takeways) of the multisig example, we also added some [key parts/concepts](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/tree/62faea5bb276b9a8aa4e9155b24c29b5d4d46392/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig#key-takeways) to pay attention when preparing a multisig transaction that you might find useful in your debugging process.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the context you've provided. Some additional thoughts:
- All three accounts you listed are now funded with >= 2 DOT, attempting to transfer 1 DOT out of the multisig still fails with `insufficientBalance`: https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/0xa1b0ce843f46bc7ea0c08b10f69b29ab2acd94445aeb24329a38cbe16b40f953
- Thank you for the context on approveAsMulti and asMulti.  Even using approveAsMulti fails every time.
- I'm attempting to create the multisig TX directly from PollkadotJS app, could it be incorrectly ordering the sigantories?

Comment: Is there really no easier way to handle multisig TXs than via a complex script? How will my non-technical signers manage with this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to the ordering of the signatories in the extrinsic you are creating. If you are manually generating the extrinsic, you need to ensure that you put the signatories in ascending order of all the other signatories beside yourself (Polkadot-JS app does this for you "behind the scenes" if you use its multisig UI).

From https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-account-multisig#multisig-accounts-with-the-polkadot-js-ui -

ADDRESSES THAT ARE PROVIDED TO THE MULTISIG WALLET ARE SORTED

Public keys of signers' wallets are compared byte-for-byte and sorted ascending before being used to generate the multisig address. For example, consider the scenario with three addresses, A, B, and C, starting with 5FUGT, 5HMfS, and 5GhKJ. If we build the ABC multisig with the accounts in that specific order (i.e. first A, then B, and C), the real order of the accounts in the multisig will be ACB. If, in the Extrinsic tab, we initiate a multisig call with C, the order of the other signatories will be first A, then B. If we put first B, then A, the transaction will fail.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for the response,.  I was not creating the extrinsic manually, I was simply using the `setIdentity` util provided by polkadotJS, so is it possible that polkadotJS is incorrectly ordering the signatories? Can you confirm it's possible to set an identity for a multisig?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the fact that the account submitting the multisig transaction , ie the `approveAsMulti`, did not have a balance of at least `20.135` DOT, which apparently is required. Credit to Polkasafe for actually surfacing a human-readable error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Multix has been created exactly to avoid these kind of issues. https://multix.chainsafe.io. Multix will order the signatories the way they should. It will also tell you if the signer doesn't have the required funds ahead of submitting a transaction. Indeed, any transaction requires a deposit of 20 DOTs that will be returned once the transaction is approved/rejected.

Finally, if you want to do complex extrinsics, you can always craft the extrinsic in pjs/apps, without having to care about the multisig, and then paste the call data into Multix. You will get the multisig extrinsic built for you, and you can submit it.